# Android Service for capture framebuffer

Tags: android

I am using a native code to capture the framebuffer using the link below

http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1473.

But my problem is that I want continous capture. Hence I am using service in Android so that it runs in background.

But my problem is that it gives low memory and dies after some time.

Then I tried with single activity and tried to capture the sam window many a times.
This time there is no problem even after 1000 counts.

The problem arises when there is service used.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without seeing your source code - you should always try to include the smallest possible application that exhibits the problem behaviour.

At a guess I would say that you have memory hungry resources that are not being cleaned up and this is happening because your memory allocation and release code is not perfectly aligned with the life-cycle of the service. You could confirm this in a couple of ways:

1. Log the explicit allocation and release of memory and make sure your service is actually executing those parts of the code.
2. Use a memory profiler to find allocations that are not being released. This might be more challenging with native code than it would be in Java.